# RHEL 7.3 syslog output text is wrapping, no new line

Tags: linux, redhat, syslog

When I `cat` a file, such as `/var/log/messages` the output is not separated into new lines, it is just a blob of wrapped text that is very difficult to read, just message after message with no new line. Is there a setting somewhere that would cause this to happen, it is happening on several of our servers.

As an example

When I run `cat /var/log/messages` I would expect to see something like:

```
2016-12-15T11:22:53.212028-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 c615 05 clock_sync
2016-12-15T11:22:54.223136-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 c618 08 no_sys_peer
2016-12-15T11:25:06.228173-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 0628 08 no_sys_peer
2016-12-15T11:25:12.233785-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 0613 03 spike_detect +0.294933 s
2016-12-15T11:29:41.762442-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.427412] FS-Cache: Loaded
2016-12-15T11:29:41.771893-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.439186] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
2016-12-15T11:29:41.775520-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.443275] Key type dns_resolver registered
2016-12-15T11:29:41.784809-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452136] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
2016-12-15T11:29:41.784814-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452141] Key type id_resolver registered
2016-12-15T11:29:41.784817-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452142] Key type id_legacy registered
```

Instead I am seeing something like:

```
2016-12-15T11:22:53.212028-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 c615 05 clock_sync 2016-12-15T11:22:54.223136-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 c618 08 no_sys_peer 2016-12-15T11:25:06.228173-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 0628 08 no_sys_peer 2016-12-15T11:25:12.233785-06:00 wilkestest.com ntpd[27156]: 0.0.0.0 0613 03 spike_detect +0.294933 s 2016-12-15T11:29:41.762442-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.427412] FS-Cache: Loaded 2016-12-15T11:29:41.771893-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.439186] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching 2016-12-15T11:29:41.775520-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.443275] Key type dns_resolver registered 2016-12-15T11:29:41.784809-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452136] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type 2016-12-15T11:29:41.784814-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452141] Key type id_resolver registered 2016-12-15T11:29:41.784817-06:00 wilkestest.com kernel: [212901.452142] Key type id_legacy registered
```

The new lines are exaggerated for formatting, Im not expecting a double spaced log file, but I would expect each new message in the log to start on a new log rather than simply a space behind the last message.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: It occurs whther I am using /dev/pts/0 and $TERM is xterm or /dev/tty1 and $TERM is linux

Comment: also, whether I ssh into the box with putty or console directly in vmware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the answer and just wanted to post here in case it may help others. In /etc/rsyslog.conf there is a parameter for $ActionFileDefaultTemplate that was set to RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat which gives a more precise date but gets rid of the \n at each message, using RSYSLOG_FileFormat or RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat as that parameter will resolve the lines being mashed together.